# What does some_script.sh || "message" means in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

The following line on a bash script:

```
$GEN_SDK $GEN_SDK_FLAGS $OUT_DIR/toolchain || panic "Cannot generate SDK toolchain!"
```

is panicking when executed. I believe the logic on this line is that if the first command runs OK, then the second one is not evaluated. But what does it mean for the first command to run OK? There's no such thing as `return true` in bash. So how does it know it didn't run OK?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the shell, all processes have an exit code (or return code).  An exit code of `0` is "truthy" in that it indicates no error has occurred (this is inverse to what one usually expects in a programming language where `0` is usually "falsy").  The bash construct of `command || othercommand` will execute `othercommand` if the exit code of `command` is anything other than `0`.  This is comparable to the construct `command && othercommand` wherein `othercommand` will be executed if and only if the exit code of `command` *is* `0`.

If you want to experiment with this, the shell expansion`$?` evaluates to the exit code of the previous command:

```
$ true; echo $?
0
$ false; echo $?
1
$ true || echo "Darned true."
$ false || echo "Lies."
Lies.
```

Comment: I added set -x on the script and then copied the command $GEN_SDK $GEN_SDK_FLAGS $OUT_DIR/toolchain and exeucted it and it does not print 0 or 1 or anything, it just executes silently. Does it means its failing or not?

Comment: Return codes are not displayed; they are, as mentioned, stored in the magic shell variable `?`.

Comment: @Gatonito the return status isn't printed. It will be saved in the special variable `$?`. Try `$GEN_SDK $GEN_SDK_FLAGS $OUT_DIR/toolchain` and then `echo $?`. If that prints `0` it worked, if it prints anything other than `0` there was a problem.